# How do I create a desktop shortcut using chrome extension programmatically?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to write a chrome extension in which I have to create a desktop shortcut of the current webpage.

This is what I tried but it did not create a shortcut but downloaded the html file instead.

```
  chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    chrome.downloads.download({
      url: tab.url,
      filename: "abc.html"
    });
  });
```

I really think this question has been asked before but I could not find the answer anywhere. I'm really sorry if this is a duplicate.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself.

I have to write a file to the disk named `filename.url` which contains the following lines:

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=url-to-webpage
```